# Is it possible to add multiselect drop down in ag grid cells in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, ag-grid

I have been trying to add a multiselect dropdown in ag-grid cells .Couldnt find proper explanation anywhere.Also please tell if we can have radio buttons inside the cells.
Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: what you tried before..?

Comment: Yes, look at `cellRenderer` https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/

Comment: you will have to add a custom cell renderer for that